# in ios 7 my application tableview text field is too small, text is not showing properly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

In ios 7 my application tableview text field shrunk, text data is not showing properly.

Could any one suggest me what to do?

EX:- username is showing U...
same other field

Comment: Give proper frame to textfields in side table.

Comment: A screenshot to demonstrate the problem would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to implement the UITableViewDelegate method `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

[UITableView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a)